# Notification does not show on 2.3.6

Tags: android, notifications

My program is calling this code from a service to show notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this).setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setContentTitle("BU").setOngoing(true).setContentText("BU is the biggest!!!");
  mNM.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

It is working on Galaxy S-III which has a version 4.1+, but it is not working neither giving an error on android v2.3.6.

I have read the api, but I might miss something. What is the problem and how can I solve it?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code as this is working for me (2.2 and up). I run this method in a seperate service class that I created. Found that my notifications does not work without a background service.

```
    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    final Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.notification_popup, message, System.currentTimeMillis());

    // used to call up this specific intent when you click on the notification
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, 
            new Intent(context, MyActivity.class), Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, contentIntent);
    notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
    manager.notify(new Random(100).nextInt(), notification);
```

Comment: ur code will work coz, u are providing a ContentIntent, and according to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011638/android-notification-not-working-on-2-3-6-samsung-galaxy-y   "GingerBread expects a ContentIntent" and my code had not one.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Notification Compat 2](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NotificationCompat2). It has been developed to handle this kind of problem.

Comment: I guess it is deprecated due to last support library.

Answer (score 0):

From Official documentation [Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)

> > This class requires API level 11 or higher.
>
> This document is hidden because your selected API level for the
>   documentation is 10. You can change the documentation API level with
>   the selector above the left navigation.
>
> For more information about specifying the API level your app requires,
>   read Supporting Different Platform Versions.

to confrim this select api level 10 from left side on the [page](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html)  you will get this dialog poped up

Comment: the thing is I am not using NotificationBuilder, check my code, I am using NotificationCompat.Builder.