# NotificationCompat.Builder on API < 11 not working

Tags: android, notifications, android-2.3-gingerbread

```
public static final String NOTIFICATION_TITLE = "Title";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(NOTIFICATION_TITLE)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                .bigText(msg))
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setContentText(msg);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

The above code works smothly on my Nexus 4 (Android 4.3) but my old Nexus One (Android 2.3.7) has still to show me a notification.

Manifest file

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="10"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<!-- GCM -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.matchtracker.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<permission
    android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application
    android:name=".AppClass"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="my.package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <activity
        android:name="my.package.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

### My Scenario

- Android Studio 0.2.8 under Ubuntu
- Android SDK Tools 22.2.1
- Android SDK Platform-tools 18.0.1
- Android SDK Build Tools 17
- Android Support Repository 2
- Android Support Library 18
- Google Play Services 12

My `build-gradle` file in my project

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+', 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.1.+'
}
```

### What have I done until now

- I am aware about Gingerbread needing `PendingIntent` that's why `.setContentIntent` is set
- I have also tried to make a function called on `if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 11)`
- Even the old (but deprecated) `Notification` does not work either
- The server works as expected because 4.3 devices receive the notifications perfectly

So, right now I have ran out of new ideas, anyone can tell me any other option why the notifications don't work on API 10 ?

Comment: have you tried `android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder`

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thank you, but I already use the support v4 library for the `NotificationCompat.Builder` that's why I can't understand my problem

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with you, apparent I just notice that effect only Gingerbread version

this is a fix worked for me
[Android : Notification not working on 2.3.6 (Samsung galaxy y)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15011638/android-notification-not-working-on-2-3-6-samsung-galaxy-y)